# How to setup project to work with odbc and mssql drivers?

Tags: sql-server, go, odbc, package

I'm trying to use the odbc driver and I'm getting errors:

```
.\main.go:5: imported and not used: "code.google.com/p/odbc/api"  
.\main.go:72: undefined: Driver  
.\main.go:76: undefined: Driver
```

I tried to work with another driver: `go get github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb` but ran unto the same type of problem.
That's why I suspect I didn't set up the environment right but unable to find the issue.

---

## My environment:

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCHAR=6
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Go\Projects 
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go 
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set TERM=dumb
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-g -O2 -m64 -mthreads
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

I installed odbc using `go get code.google.com/p/odbc`
Ran test and it finished fine:
`C:\Go\Projects\src\code.google.com\p\odbc>go test -mssrv=.\sqlexp -v -run=MS
...
--- PASS: TestMSSQLUTF16ToUTF8 (0.00 seconds) 
=== RUN TestMSSQLExecStoredProcedure
--- PASS: TestMSSQLExecStoredProcedure (0.01 seconds) 
PASS
ok code.google.com/p/odbc 0.574s`

**My Code:** *(copied from mssql_test.go):*

```
package main  
import (  
    "code.google.com/p/odbc/api"  
    "database/sql"       
    "flag"  
    "fmt"  
    "os"  
    "runtime"      
    "testing"  
    "time"  
)  

func mssqlConnect() (db *sql.DB, stmtCount int, err error) {  
    .........  
    return db, db.Driver().(*Driver).Stats.StmtCount, nil  
}  
func closeDB(t *testing.T, db *sql.DB, shouldStmtCount, ignoreIfStmtCount int) {  
    s := db.Driver().(*Driver).Stats  
    ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.\main.go:5: imported and not used: "code.google.com/p/odbc/api"  
.\main.go:72: undefined: Driver  
.\main.go:76: undefined: Driver
```

Delete `import`

```
    "code.google.com/p/odbc/api"
```

Add `import`

```
    "code.google.com/p/odbc"
```

Replace `*Driver` with `*odbc.Driver`. For example,

```
    return db, db.Driver().(*odbc.Driver).Stats.StmtCount, nil
```

and

```
    s := db.Driver().(*odbc.Driver).Stats
```

---

```
./main.go:5: imported and not used: "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" as mssql
```

Change `import` to

```
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
```

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)

func main() {
    conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", makeConnStr())
}
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Import declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Import_declarations)
>
> To import a package solely for its side-effects (initialization), use
>   the blank identifier as explicit package name:
>
> ```
> import _ "lib/math"
> ```

Comment: I spent 2 days researching this issue. Thank you.

Comment: One more question about the go-mssql package "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb".  I get an error:  _"imported and not used: "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb" as mssql"_  by running code: package main  import("github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb") **conn, err := sql.Open("mssql", makeConnStr())**

Comment: @PaulS.: See my revised answer.

Comment: Google didn't know about this type of error. I've been learning Go for about a week now. Lack of good examples and general information is impressive. Thank you for your help. Paul.